# Retrieving child directive scope from parent through element.find

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I can't use "require" because i have a directive that can have many different parents which i cannot predict exactly who they will be. What i need to do is in each parent be able to retrieve the controller or scope of the child directive and invoque a method to disable a button. I have a plunker which shows the problem.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Od1mJZOq1ep54pj6k6ti?p=preview

```
  .directive('parent', function($compile, $rootScope) {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {},
  templateUrl: 'parent.html',
  link: postLinkFunction
};

function postLinkFunction(scope, element, attributes) {
  var directive = element.find('child');
  var directiveScope = directive.isolateScope();

  console.log(directiveScope);
}
})
.directive('anotherParent', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {},
  templateUrl: 'parent.html',
  link: postLinkFunction
};

function postLinkFunction(scope, element, attributes) {
  var directive = element.find('child');
  var directiveScope = directive.isolateScope();

  console.log(directiveScope);
}
})
.directive('child', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {},
  controller: function($scope, $element) {
    var vm = this;

    $scope.isDisabled = false;

    $scope.disableMenu = function () {
      $scope.isDisabled = true;
    };

    $scope.number = 1;
  },
  templateUrl: 'child.html'
};
});
```

The isolateScope is empty even if i have populated it, also the child directive has to have isolate scope can't share scope with the parent, and as i said i can't use require. In theory the element.find way is hacky but easy to implement but i can't make it work. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!.

Comment: Did you try `.scope()`?

Comment: I did, and nothing is bound to the scope(). You can try it in the plunk

Comment: You can path variable into isolated scope. Try something like in [this demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/v126T51JDrUy4IL0cNsH)

Comment: Yeah that will have to do, i still don't know why it doesn't work as is. Probably something to do with the compiling of the function, maybe it doesn't have place before the element.find is performed so the isaloteScope is not defined. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent module should comunicate with childs through variables in isolated scope like this:

```
app.directive("testDir", function() {

  var directive = {
    restrict: "A",
    template: "<div><input value='TestButton' type='button' data-ng-disabled='IsDisabled'></div>",
    scope: 
    {
      IsDisabled: "=isDisabled"
    }
  };

  return directive;
});
```

Here's working [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/v126T51JDrUy4IL0cNsH)

Comment: Yes, i'll implement it this way. Thanks again, sometimes less is more i guess hehe.

Answer (score 4):

In angular link process is executed from top to bottom so in your case you're trying to get child scope before it's created, you can fix this by adding function to scope and execute it on click:

```
  scope.click = function() {
    var directive = element.find('child');
    var directiveScope = directive.isolateScope();
    console.log(directiveScope);
  };
```

```html
<div class="tabbable">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <child></child>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="click()">click</button>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/HZruQMnkbs99H8I3lqoE?p=preview

Comment: Ahh that was what was happening, thanks a lot for clarifying that. Unfortunately in my scenario i can't wait for the child to load in an async way. But i suspected it had something to do with the compile or digest process of angular.